# Having trouble with arrow function in my application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Everything works fine until I add the initial players.map arrow function step is implemented on line 52 (Players List comment). The scoreboard is supposed to show the name values under it using the player's array everything shows up when I inspect the element with dev tools until this step maybe it is something I am not catching watched the video 5x.

Here is a link to the site: https://codingoni.github.io/React-Project/
Link to the Code:https://github.com/CodingOni/React-Project

I have tried looking over syntax numerous times

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Scoreboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


const players = [
  {
    name: "Guil",
    score: 50
  },
  {
    name: "Treasure",
    score: 85
  },
  {
    name: "Ashley",
    score: 95
  },
  {
    name: "James",
    score: 80
  }
  ];
  const Header = (props) => {
    return(
      <header>
          <h1>{props.title}</h1>
              <span className="stats">Player: {props.totalPlayers} </span>
      </header>
    );
  }


  const Player = (props) => {
      return( <div className="player">
                 <span className="player-name"> {props.name} </span>
             <Counter score={props.score} />
               </div> 
            );
    }


  const Counter = (props) => { 
      return( <div className="counter">
  <button className="counter-action decrement">-</button>
             <span className="counter-score">{props.score}</span>
             <button className="counter-action increment">+</button>
             </div>
            );
  }

  const App = (props) =>{ 
      return( 
          <div className="scoreboard">
          <Header title="Scoreboard" totalPlayers={"1"}/>  
  //      {Players List*/}
        {props.initialPlayers.map( player =>
         <Player 
        name={player.name}
        score={player.score}
        /> 
      )}

          <Player name="Tyrique" score={20} /> 
          <Player name="Tyrique" score={30} /> 
          <Player name="Tyrique" score={10} /> 
          <Player name="Tyrique" score={15} /> 

          </div> ); } 

  ReactDOM.render( 
        <App initialPlayers={players} />,
     document.getElementById('root') );
```

The names and score to show up on the board

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
{props.initialPlayers.map( (player, index) => {
    return <Player 
    key={index}
    name={player.name}
    score={player.score}
    /> 
  })}
```

Comment: still nothing :(

Comment: What is it that isn't working? I put your code in sandbox and it seems to render everything alright.

Comment: there is a scoreboard that is supposed to be showing up and nothing is rendering.  It was working fine before iterated through the array and added the arrow function.